# Add a new field in every document through aggregation & $facet in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My Sample data looks like below:

```
Category      response
Privacy         1
Mobile          1
Privacy         1
Privacy         2
```

I want add new field `Total` taken from sum of all `response` field values. Required output as below :

```
Category      response   Total
Privacy         1         5
Mobile          1         5
Privacy         1         5
Privacy         2         5
```

How can I get this output in mongodb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update :** As value of `Total` is not the fixed one, updated answer with question :

```
/** Using 'facet' as we need docs to be returned in result 
  * (Can also be done without 'facet' by pushing all docs into an array in '$group' but it may not work for large datasets) */
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      data: [ { $match: {} } ], /** Get all docs without any filter */
      total: [
        {
          $group: { /** Group all docs & sum-up 'result' field */
            _id: "",
            Total: { $sum: "$response" }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$total"
  },
  /** Merge 'total' field into 'data' & make data field as new root for documents */
  {
    $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: [ "$total", "$data" ] } }
  }
])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jivYhaSE8vI)

**Old :** If `Total` is same value for all docs .

If it's the same value needed to be added across all documents in aggregation result then just use aggregation stage [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) :

```
{ $addFields : { Total :5 } }
```

Comment: It is not fix 5 It changes as new document inserted.

Comment: @KamleshKanazariya : I just realized you don't need to do `$unwind : total` instead of that additional stage - In `$mergeObjects` you can replace `$total` with `{$arrayElemAt :['$total',0]}` !!